# Netshare syntax(CLI, command line) to add share to folder on remote machine

Tags: powershell, command-line, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I would like to know if somebody knows the correct syntax for giving a folder a share on remote network machine folder's.
Please write a syntax you know for sure that it's working